# Backup user accounts in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup

I have recently created a new Ubuntu system. I have created 5 users by the name of `ellie`, `james`, `john`, `tom` and `emily`. Essentially what I want to do is to create a backup of all these users as a TAR'd and GZIPPED archive. This would include their home directory files as well as usernames and passwords.

As this system is running Ubuntu, tar is already installed. How would this be done?

I have a USB plugged into my computer by the name `ESD-USB`. If possible I would like the backup directed to this USB. Again, I am new so I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Which part of the accounts do you intend to back up? Their files in the home directory? Their names and UIDs?

Comment: … and/or maybe passwords they use to log in?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I've updated the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command:

```
cd /home
tar cvfz /media/ESD-USB/backup.tar.gz {ellie,james,john,tom,emily}
```

But, it could be better to have multiple backups files, one per user:

```
cd /home
for d in {ellie,james,john,tom,emily}
do
  tar cvfz /media/ESD-USB/backup-${d}.tar.gz $d
done
```

I assume your USB drive mounted on `/media/ESD-USB`. The command `mount` can confirm.

If there are no other users in `/home`, `*` instead of `{ellie,james,john,tom,emily}` can be handy and will match a 6th user when created.

You can have variant, like `tar cvfz /media/ESD-USB/backup.tar.gz /home/{ellie,james,john,tom,emily}`, not strictly equivalent. This depends if you want `home` to be prefixed in the backuped files.

But, you should try a `tar cvfz file.tar.gz directory` with a little directory, then `tar xvfz file.tar.gz` to extract the backuped file, and see how that's working. It is important to be familiar with the backup procedure AND the restore procedure.

For the passwords,

```
cd /home
grep '^\(ellie\|james\|john\|tom\|emily\):' /etc/passwd > passwd-extract
grep '^\(ellie\|james\|john\|tom\|emily\):' /etc/shadow> shadow-extract
grep '^\(ellie\|james\|john\|tom\|emily\):' /etc/group> group-extract

tar cfvz /media/ESD-USB/passwd.tar.gz \
   passwd-extract shadow-extract group-extract
rm passwd-extract shadow-extract group-extract
```

Note `group-extract` only save the groups with the same name as the user. But not the memberships of the user. Their is something missing.

The full group memberships can be extract with:
`grep '\(:\|,\)\(ellie\|james\|john\|tom\|emily\)' /etc/group> group-extract` but the restoration may be a little difficult if we have to preserve other memberships. (The whole related groups are exported, including members which are not amoung the 5 users).

On a system where the group are restored, we have to avoid changing the numbers of system groups from the newly installed system. And some of the number are parts of this extraction.

On a system, I have the group `video:x:44:loyer`. As `loyer`, I could want my membership to this group backuped. But on a fresh system, if I have 42 instead of 44, I would wish to restore the `loyer`name from the backup, but keep the 44. Then, saving (and restoring) groups partially can be tricky.

Comment: Correct lines from `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` should be added to the backups. Groups affiliation also.

Comment: A proposal for passwd and shadow is added, but group is missing and more tricky.

Comment: Wow. The effort you've put into explaining this is remarkable. This worked perfectly and made total sense. Thank you so much.